# Visualizing trees of the final model in Caret

Tags: r, visualization, random-forest, r-caret

Is it possible to visualize trees in Caret final model trained by random forest?

```
 train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5,savePredictions =  TRUE,classProbs = TRUE)
 output <- train(Species~., data=iris, trControl=train_control, method="rf")
```

I would like to know depth of the trees and visualize some trees of the final model, I found out that there's `output$finalModel$forest` for the output but I don't know how to use it for plots.

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this previous question [How to actually plot a sample tree from randomForest::getTree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41443/141956)

Comment: @G5W I need a way to visualize   getTree(output$finalModel,1,labelVar = TRUE)   which is not well explained in that answer

Comment: A little googling did not harm anyone: [Plotting trees from (caret) Random Forest models with ggraph](https://shiring.github.io/machine_learning/2017/03/16/rf_plot_ggraph)